# Creating Android UI with photoshop - How to implement final product?

Tags: android, user-interface, implementation, photoshop

Let's say you've created an app's UI in photoshop. For the purpose of this question I'll try to keep it simple. You have a background color, a few custom buttoms, and a variety of other things.

My question is this - how do you implement that final product into the code? How would you export what you drew in Photoshop to android code, where you can link all of the buttons, etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would export each component individually and then use Android Styles to apply them to your layout.

For example, you'd export your background image and use `android:background` to set it as the background in your layout.

You'd export each state of your buttons as an individual image, and use a state list drawable to set them as the images for focused, pressed, not pressed states.

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with it a bit, but I have a feeling I'll get hung up on the button part. I still can't find any resources for actually implementing this (or I wouldn't be asking this question), but maybe you have found some that you could point me to? Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Here you go: [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)